# Error when trying to extract files from a zip file

Tags: download, zip, archiving

When I try to extract files and opening the zip itself I get this error:

```
!   C:\Users\Loko\Downloads\Textbook_1.zip: Unexpected end of archive
```

Some people say redownloading is the only fix but it wont work for me. Also tried to redownload it twice and the 2nd time it just failed downloading. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error breaks the archive extracting algorithm and stops the extracting process so that the stored file couldn’t be extracted until this error fixed.

Try the following(if you use *Winrar*):

1. Double click on archive file.
2. It will be open using WinRar utility.
3. Now right click on your file and select `repair`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The process which I am sharing here is the best free technique to extract data from inaccessible ZIP file. The steps are given in the post below:

[Repair ZIP File | Bela. N Blog](http://nalavadebela.wordpress.com/2014/04/05/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-archive-file/)

It will help you!

Thanks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.