# zip: Unexpected end of archive

Tags: zip, archiving, extract, winrar, winzip

When I try to extract my `1.15GB` downloaded `.zip` file am getting following error:

> !   D:\N750XXUCNG6_N750ODDCNG5_INU.zip: Unexpected end of
>   archive

I have tried this https://superuser.com/a/729707/347907

but this didn't solve my problem, while doing that I got this error:

> ```
> !   Write error in the file . Probably the disk is full
> Invalid access to memory location.
> ```

NOTE: the filepath drive has `40BG` free space. I also copied the `.zip` file to another computer but still the same issue.

---

[image]

*This is the actual size showing for the `.zip` file*

[image] *now see the size of the content inside the `.zip` its `0`*

Comment: this is a common message when the archive is corrupt, or missing pieces in the case of a multi-part archive. if you have any parity files, you may be able to use them to repair the file.

Comment: @FrankThomas see the edit and now what i need to do ??

Comment: That definitely looks like a corrupted archive. Specifically, it appears the zip file catalog is corrupted: there is no reasonable way a 0 byte file can result in a >1 GB archive file. I would recommend trying to download it again.

Comment: Your archive is corrupt.  Restore it from a backup and/or download it again.

Comment: The archive file is incomplete. The actual size should be `1.23 GiB` (`1322037565` bytes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've sorted out  the problem,

Today again downloaded the same file(.zip) in *chrome*, the same problem raised.
at last I've installed and downloaded using <kbd>Internet Download Manager</kbd>
*thank god <kbd>IDM</kbd> saved  my day*.
Now everything is fine.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, **it appears that your .zip file is corrupted.**

Specifically, the *catalog* (which lists the contents of the zip file, and is stored at the end of the file) seems to be corrupted. That is indicated by the only file listed by WinRAR being reported as having a size of 0 bytes, whereas the archive itself is over a gigabyte in size.

Aside from the fact that a 0 byte size for a .md5 file appears rather odd, *there is no reasonable way* a correct archive which contains a single file with no data in it can balloon to over a gigabyte. That should be on the order of a few hundred bytes to a kilobyte; you are *six orders of magnitude* off in terms of file size compared to what the catalog indicates for contents of the archive.

There is a remote possibility that you might be able to use the test/repair functionality of a packer (such as WinRAR, WinZip, 7Zip, or something else; I don't really know off the top of my head what's available these days) to repair the archive. However, I imagine those work primarily on a per-compressed-file basis, and from the looks of it, that archive should contain two files: a .tar.md5, and the corresponding .tar (possibly itself compressed into something like a .tar.gz file, but that makes no difference in this case).

**You probably need to download the zip file again,** and hope it's not corrupted where you are currently storing the (hopefully) good copy.

> no... it took 6 and half hrs to download

Sorry about that.

**I would suggest keeping the copy you currently have,** and storing the fresh download alongside it. That way, if the second download doesn't work either, you can compare the two: if the two downloads are different, there's likely something flaky about your connection or local storage, and if they are identical but both corrupted, it's highly likely that the copy you are downloading *from* is corrupted. It won't necessarily help you fix the problem, but it should help you determine where the real problem is and if possible allow you to take mitigative steps from there.